# How Springboot lock the libs' version, like Rails's Gemfile.lock?

Tags: spring-boot

I understand there is library dependency management in Springboot so that the correct version of starter kits will be picked for the Springboot version. However I do not fully understand how the third-party libs' versions are controlled.

For example, in build.gradle file, we can use a lib like this:

`implementation('org.liquibase:liquibase-core')` .

I know that Gradle's logic is to pick the latest version if no version is specified. I am not sure if there are any tools like a lock file to lock down **ALL** the versions used by this application, or we have to specify the version like:

`compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.4'` ?

So that we can be confident that all the libs used in the team are identical.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice recommended by gradle is to declare dependencies without versions and use dependency constraints.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core'
}

dependencies {
    constraints {
        implementation 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.6.2'
    }
}
```